# crashlytics Answers not showing in Multi flavor app

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, google-fabric

We have an application working great with Crashlytic and Answers.
We need to make a different flavour for this app.
So, we have Gradle compilation working Ok, and making two different APKs for two different brandings.
As soon as we changed the "applicationId" on build.gradle, the new flavor started to appear on Dashboard.
But, when the app tries to log events in Answers, only the old flavor is showing the info.
When we enable debugging in Fabric, the new one is showing "D/Answers: Analytics collection disabled" on logcat, but crashlytics is working ok.
Do we need to make something else on the new flavor to get Answers working ? maybe a different API key????

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Angel, Todd from Fabric. What are you seeing on the Answers screens in your dashboard? You either need to enable Answers in the dashboard for this app, or add the new package name to Crashlytics by adding it as a new app. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there.Thanks for your answer. In the dashboard, the answer tab is empty, nothing is show. In the crashlytics tab, all seems Ok, and it show a "Enable Answers" button, but when i push it, nothing happens and the answers screen shows empty again. How can i enable Answers? Are there some kind of setting i must enable??? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a new API key.

> Fabric uses an API key and build secret to authenticate your apps to your organization. All of your apps use the same Fabric organization key and secret.

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/api-keys.html

Fabric recognizes this as a new Android application (based on applicationId set in Manifest file), meaning that you have to enable Answers for that application separately.

Comment: Head to your Fabric dashboard for the app and then click on any of the icon's in the sidebar that are greyed out and you'll be able to enable it.